# Shortcode attributes without values and with special characters

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

1. Can Wordpress shortcodes have attributes without values like this?

   ```
   [foo some_att]
   ```

   I know it can be like this:

   ```
   [foo some_att=""]
   ```
2. Can I have shortcode values like this (with curly braces)?

   ```
   [foo path="{'quality': '720p', 'mp4': 'PATH_TO_MP4_VIDEO'}"]
   ```

Answer (score 3):

1. You sure can! [RichJenks](https://richjenks.com/unnamed-wordpress-shortcode-attributes/) has a short yet informative article on implementing this functionality, which boils down to defining a new function that can tell you if a flag (argument with no associated value) is present in your `$atts` array:

   ```
   function is_flag( $flag, $atts ) {
       foreach ( $atts as $key => $value )
           if ( $value === $flag && is_int( $key ) ) return true;
       return false;
   }
   ```

   After defining this function, you can reference `is_flag()` in your shortcode function to tell if the flag has been provided as part of the shortcode invocation:

   ```
   if is_flag( 'some_att', $atts )
       // flag is present
   else
       // flag is not present
   ```
2. Unfortunately, the example you've provided wouldn't work as an argument value with the Wordpress shortcode parser. According to the official [Wordpress documentation on the Shortcode API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Attributes):

   > Attribute values must never contain the following characters:
   >
   > - Square braces: [ ]
   > - Quotes: " '

   Since your example makes use of the single-quote character (`'`), it is officially unsupported by the shortcode parsing engine.

Comment: Would this work?   [foo path="{quality: 720p, mp4: PATH_TO_MP4_VIDEO}"] . could I get my data?

Comment: In the sense that the shortcode processor would accept it as valid: ot should, considering it would no longer use any restricted characters. In the sense of whether or not it would work for your current codebase: it's impossible to tell without more information outside the scope of this question.

Comment: How would I get quality and mp4 in shortcode? I can only get path with $atts['path']

Comment: @Toniq it's impossible to say for certain what you could leverage without knowing more about the solution as a whole. In any case (as I mentioned), this would most likely be outside the scope of this question, and you'd likely attract better answers if you broke this out into a different question with a new minimal, complete, and verifiable example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for first question.

```
is_int( array_search( 'some_att', $atts ?: [] ) )
```